# Pasar Variables de un widget a otro

Tags: flutter, dart

¿Como puedo pasar una variable de un widget a otro?

Quiero que cuando pulse el botón `login` imprima el usuario (ósea donde imprime el "si" que imprima la variable usuario del otro widget).

Sinceramente vengo de python y esto me esta desconcertando un poco . Las definiciones aquí no se si se hacen en otra carpeta o que... pero bueno voy aprendiendo.

```
  class CamposUsuario extends StatelessWidget {
  final String texto;
  CamposUsuario({required this.texto});
  final usuario = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), labelText: "$texto"),
      obscureText: (this.texto == "Password") ? true : false,
      controller: usuario,
    );
  }
}

class BotonLogin extends StatelessWidget {
  const BotonLogin({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60),
      elevation: 7,
      onPressed: () {
        print('si');
      },
      color: Colors.amber[900],
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Text("Login"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar datos de un widget a otro, por lo que aplica lo explicado en [FlutterDev Cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) y así avanzar mas rápido.
Que sería incluir los datos a pasar en el momento que navegas de un widget a otro en tu caso.

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => WidgetB(dato: datoQueVoyEnviar),
          ),
        );
```

Pero si estamos hablando de un login te recomiendo que veas en [FlutterDev Cookbook Form](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#forms)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Ejemplo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  **final usuario = TextEditingController();**

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return **Form**(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            **controller: usuario,**
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Ingresar usuario',
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                **print('el valor ingresado en el campo usuario es ${usuario.text}');**

              },
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que estés muy bien, para compartir información entre widgets recomiendo fuertemente el uso de [providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/install) pues te ayudar a compartir información no solo entre un widget sino que en cualquier widget dentro de tu app así esté en la ultima pantalla :

Para utilizarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente
Crea tu provider

```dart
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    class Sesion with ChangeNotifier {
      String _user = 'Daniel';
      get user {
        return _user;
      }
      set user( String nombre ) {
        this._user = nombre;
        notifyListeners();
      }
```

En este generé el elemento para compartir la sesión en este caso el nombre del usuario. No necesariamente puedes tener un solo provider puedes crear cuantos quieras ...

```dart
class UtilidadesUser with ChangeNotifier {
  String _company = 'Weincode';
  get company {
    return _company;
  }
  set company( String nombre ) {
    this._company = nombre;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Pero ... ¿Cómo los podemos utilizar?
Lo primero es que entre más alto esté el provider en el árbol de widgets mucho mejor pues nos permitirá compartir con sus hijos descendientes, por lo tanto podemos hacer lo siguiente :

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider( create: (context) => Sesion() ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider( create: (context) => UtilidadesUser() ),
      ],
      child:Home()
    );
  }
}
```

Como vemos el Multiprovider es el papá de Home si presentáramos rutas internas sería el papá de todas ellas.

Ahora resta utilizar en algún widget :

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final companyInfo = Provider.of<UtilidadesUser>(context);
    Widget element =Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text(companyInfo.company) ,),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Build some widgets!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ),
    );
    return  element;
  }
```

Si de casualidad deseas actualizar la información de un provider también lo puedes hacer fácilmente :

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final companyInfo = Provider.of<UtilidadesUser>(context);
    Widget element =Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text(companyInfo.company) ,),
      body: Center(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon( Icons.account_balance  ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            companyInfo.company   = 'Stack Overflow Español';
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
    return  element;
  }
```

al tener un listener de los cambios el título cambiará automáticamente.

Te dejo el link con el ejemplo completo :D . Saludos

https://gist.github.com/Danielherresan/11f730840aa0987ab00a9f46fd78f2ac